# Connect to Oracle Database which protected by VPN

Tags: java, oracle, vpn

If I want to access database then I need to connect to VPN first and then I am able to access oracle database. But Is there any way to connect to oracle database from java program to access oracle database which is protected by VPN.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to connect via a VPN to access the database, Java will have to connect through the same VPN to connect; the access paths to the network destination (the database) doesn't know or care whether it is a real person, or a Java program, trying to connect to the destination.  So the Java program will have to execute on a computer that has the VPN connection set up before it connects.

Comment: Is there any possibility to connect to Data base from java program without using VPN connectivity? FYI, I have tried using normal JDBC  but it is connected to db since VPN is restricting us to connect directly from your java program.

Comment: No, that is the whole purpose of VPN; to provide a (secured) private network connection to a resource.